# Prepositional phrase agreement with the rest of the sentence

Tags: verb-agreement

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> Our testers are actually very nice people with a soul.

Assuming it is grammatically correct, is it logically correct? Am I implying that all of our testers share a single soul?

I understand that there are less confusing alternatives, such as

> Our testers are actually very nice people with souls.

... but I'm only concerned about the correctness of the first sentence.

Comment: Since sharing a soul is semantically unlikely, the first would be understood as the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read literally, your first sentence does suggest that all the testers share a soul. But since the common understanding of the meaning of *soul* makes this unlikely, no one would expect that you actually meant it, so they would interpret it as your second sentence.

But if you replace *soul* with something that's likely to be shared, the inference would be taken. E.g.

> Our testers are very nice people living in a house.

suggests that your testers are housemates.

Comment: Your example would be more relevant if you said *...people* ***with*** *a house*.

Comment: That was how I first wrote it, but the sharing implication didn't seem as strong.